# Dispaying different text when songs are being played in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of many songs in a playlist and I want to display different text whenever each song is being played while using the same area of the page. If there are no songs playing, the area is blank.

How would I do this fairly simply?

This is the code I have, I didn't include the full list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#music">Music that reminds of you</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Message">Messagse to you</a></li>
</ul>

<audio  id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" >
    <source src='C:\Users\leen_\Desktop\VALEY\music\Sleeping At Last - Saturn.mp3'>
    </audio>
<div id="musicPlaylist" class="playlist">
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="activeSong">
            <a onclick="myFunction()" id = "Saturn" href='...Saturn.mp3'>
                Saturn
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='...closer .mp3'>
                Closer
            </a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then this

```
<script>
    var audio;
    var playlist;
    var tracks;
    var current;
    
    init();
    function init(){
        current = 0;
        audio = $('#audio');
        playlist = $('#playlist');
        tracks = playlist.find('li a');
        len = tracks.length;
        audio[0].volume = .50;
        audio[0].play();
        playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            link = $(this);
            current = link.parent().index();
            run(link, audio[0]);
        });
        audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
            current++;
            if(current == len){
                current = 0;
                link = playlist.find('a')[0];
            }
            else{
                link = playlist.find('a')[current];
            }
            run($(link),audio[0]);
        });
    }
    function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: So every time a new song begins, a different message should appear in `<a href="#Message">Messagse to you</a>`? What are the messages, and which song does each of them go with?

Comment: Check this - [Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) , you can use the `playing` or `pause` event to complete your needs